# Firefox - removed option to disable images?

Tags: firefox

FF had a setting, to disable images - for a sites list. This option (button which opens sites list to disable images) is removed from "Contents" tab of options, in FF 24 for Win. I cannot edit it now. How to edit it (or reset it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For individual sites it's possible to reset/set the permissions when visiting the site -- right-click > [View Page Info](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/page-info-window-view-technical-details-about-page) > **Permissions**: **Load Images**.

Another way would be to enter [Permissions Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/permissions-manager-give-ability-store-passwords-set-cookies-more), select the site on the left, and **Forget About This Site** on the right (though image options aren't listed as of now, it works). Alternatively via History Library (Ctrl-Shift-H), search for, and right-click the site on the right-side pane > **Forget About This Site**. Please note that both these methods also [resets all the settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-recent-browsing-search-and-download-history) for the particular site to the defaults as shown when selecting **All Sites** (on the left) in the Permissions Manager.

It's also possible to reset all permissions (including images) for all sites to the defaults by deleting permissions.sqlite in the [Profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) after exiting Firefox.

[Profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder)

[Profile contents](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Files_and_folders_in_the_profile)

PS: For a blanket permissions setting for images, see [permissions.default.image](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Permissions.default.image) in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config).

[about:config Entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)